# Why isn't Parashurama worshipped like the other Vishnu Avatars?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, parashurama

Vishnu Avatars like Rama and Krishna get worshipped in all main regions of India. But why doesn't Parashurama get worshipped that much? Is there some reason for it? Parashurama is the longest-serving Avatar of Vishnu. He is even said to be living in the mortal world and will train Kalki avatar. So why doesn't he get worshipped that much?

Comment: A thought - wouldn't you say that Rama and Krishna (and Buddha, if you want to count him) are actually the exceptions here? I mean, have you ever seen anybody worship Matsya or Kurma or Varaha or any of the other avatars of the Dashavataram? There could certainly be a deep answer as to why Parashurama isn't worshipped, but it's also possible that the answer is just "people don't worship _most_ avatars of Vishnu, and Parashurama is no exception". (Good question, +1)

Comment: @senshin updated answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Where did you get the idea that Parashurama is the longest-serving avataram of Vishnu?  Varaha has been on the earth for much longer.  That's why the original name of Tirupati is "Adi Varaha Kshetra", because it was where Varaha was living long before Venkateshwara came, and Venkatehswara actually had to get permission from Varaha in order to live there.

Comment: Varaha inhabiting Tirupati is described in the Venkatachala Mahatmya of the Skanda Purana: http://hdl.handle.net/10689/13009

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Parshurama is immortal avatar and he lived through so many yuga's.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Varaha is also immortal and he has lived for many more yugas than Parashurama.  Parashurama has only been living for the past three yugas, the Treta Yuga, the Dwapara Yuga, and the present Kali Yuga.  Varaha has been living in Tirupati since the beginning of the Kalpa (which is why it's called Shwetavaraha Kalpa), and there have been 28 Mahayugas in the Kalpa so far.  So Varaha is about 37 times as old as Parashurama.

Comment: I actually vastly underestimated Varaha's age.  There haven't only been 28 Mahayugas in the present Shwetavaraha Kalpa.  Rather, there have been 28 Mahayugas so far in the present Vaivasvata Manvantara, and there are 14 Manvantaras in a Kalpa.  (There are about 71 Mahayugas in a Manvantara, and 1000 Mahayugas in a Kalpa.) The Vaivasvata Manvantara is the 7th Manvanthara of the Shwetavaraha Kalpa.  So I think Varaha is actually hundreds of times as old as Parashurama.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan before coming to hinduism.se i didn't know that varaha lived that longer and narsimha also played other crucial role too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma What crucial role of Narasimha are you talking about?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan i mean that other avatars of shiva and narsimha. Didn't know that story before.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Oh, you mean this? http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2479/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan sorry, did not get why did you said above "Parashurama has only been living for the past three yugas"  ?

Comment: @Friendy Sorry, that comment was written back when I didn't know that different incarnations took place in different Mahayugas.  That was before I encountered passages from the Matsya Purana and Skanda Purana that set me straight.  I discuss the Matsya Purana passage in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36 In any case, the correct information  is that Parashurama was born in the 19th Mahayuga.  That's still far younger than Varaha though.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan,yup Varaha is way more older ,  I just have been browsing your answers and comments for getting more and more information , I looked at your other answers related to different mahayuga and was confused with this one. :)

Comment: @Friendy I'm glad you're reading my answers and comments!  I hope you're also reading my questions; that's what I put the most effort into writing.

Comment: Because the Bhagavatam, Ramayana, and Mahabharata captured the hearts, imaginations, and love of us all. The stories about Rama and Krishna are extensive, from childhood till death.
There is much less information about Parashurama. There are not thick volumes written about him for us to learn.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Did anyone actually meet Varaha in the present yuga, is it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yeah, Venkateshwara met Varaha in the present Yuga.  Varaha gave permission to Venkateshwara stay in Adi Varaha Kshetra (aka Tirumala), as long as those who worship Venkateshwara first worship Varaha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan who is longest living?Vamana or Varaha?....Lord Vamana protects Sutala lok where Mahabali stays.recently I heard from a person that he is longest lived.

Comment: Ankit parasurama is worshipped day in and day out.. If you perform any yagnya karma, He is worshipped as one who accepts Havis and present in Agni of yagnya And he is present in everybody body as temperature and he is the one responsible for speech .. vak is agni.. where you do Agni upasena you need think of parasuram as antharyami  in that agni.. In other tradition they categarise parasurama as avesha avatara because they cannot explain, similarly vedavyasa. So before sweekara of any sampradhaya you should analyse whether is right or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All forms are His. He promised to descend to earth to save the nobles and to punish the evil when ever required, in this process He either takes a form on His own or influence(may give power) someone to act on His behalf or He may wish to put His amsa (a part) in any being for the cause.

Each avatara is meant for different purpose and the way of worship to that deity and the return we get out of it differs among! Each deity in various forms worshiped in various ways blesses with different results! (like Ganapathy worshipped as lakshmi ganapathi, natya ganapathi, maha ganapathy, arka ganapathy...)

The rishuis (Seers) on doing exhaustive worship on a deity understands these and teaches to the fellow people whom to worship, how to worship for a specific purpose. So wrong way of worshiping may give wrong results by any deity.

Parasurama amsa(a part of avatar) is just limited to kill the evil kings, parasuram later approached lord dattatreya for liberation, parasuram is not purna(complete) avatar.