# Which scripture describes Lakshmi pacifying Narsimha?

Tags: lakshmi, narasimha

Lord Narsimha is one of the prominent Vishnu's incarnation. Vishnu is believed to have taken Narsimha avatar to destroy the demon king Hiranyakashipu, as [described in Shrimad Bhagwat](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/8)

Also, in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimha#Lord_Narasi.E1.B9.81ha_and_Prahl.C4.81da) it is mentioned that after killing Hiraṇyakaśipu, none of the present demigods are able to calm Narasiṁha's wrath. After Hiraṇyakaśipu was killed, the Lord continued to be very angry, and the demigods, could not pacify Him.

So in order to pacify Lord Narsimha, all the gods and goddesses call his consort, **Lakshmi**, who assumes the form of Pratyangira and pacifies the Lord.

**My Question is** : Which scripture describe Lakshmi assuming form of [Pratyangira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira), also called as **Narasimhi**, to pacify Vishnu?

*Side Note*: As per [Shrimad Bhagvat](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/9), it is Prahlāda who came forward and pacified the Lord’s anger, and not Lakshmi.

Comment: There's basically four stories about how Narasimha's anger subsided: there is the Prahlada story you mentioned, there's the Sharabha/Gandhaberunda story I discuss [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2479/36), there's the Pratyangira Devi story, and then there is the story of Chenchu Lakshmi, where Lakshmi incarnates as a tribal girl and Narasimha falls in love with her.  But I don't know of any scriptural basis of either the Pratyangira Devi story or the Chenchu Lakshmi story.

Comment: I think Pratyangira Devi's name is mentioned in some Shakta Agamas, in the course of listing various Shaktis.  And I think the Shakta Agamas might even describe a procedure to worship her.  But I don't know of any scripture that actually describes the story of Pratyangira Devi pacifying Narasimha.  It may just be folklore.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan According to Wiki, Prathyangira is also mentioned in the Hindu epic Ramayana. Indrajit was performing "Nikumbala yaga" (a sacred ritual to worship Prathyangira) while Rama and his soldiers were waging war in Lanka. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira#In_Hindu_Epics So after all Prathyangira seems to have some mention in scripture, but not sure if her pacifying Narsimha is mentioned anywhere. Hence, my Quesion

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I was kind-of aware of 3 out of 4 stories except story of Chenchu Lakshmi. Where can I find this story? I know you mentioned it is not part of scripture, but where you heard it?

Comment: Pratyangira Devi is not mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana at all.  I thunk the website that Wikipedia cites is misunderstanding things.  Nikumbhila is not the name of a Yagna, and Indrajit did not do the Yagna in Ayyavadi in Tamil Nadu.  Nikumbhila is the name of a place, a garden at the western end of Lanka where Indrajit performed a Yagna to produce a chariot to render him invincible.

Comment: Here is the chapter of the Yuddha Kanda of the Ramayana where Vibhishana tells Rama to kill Indrajit before he does the Yagna: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga84/yuddha_84_frame.htm Here is the chapter of the Uttara Kanda where Brahma grants Indrajit the boon of invincibility: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-35 And here's an earlier Uttara Kanda chapter describing the sorts of Yagnas Indrajit performed at Nikumbhila: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30 So Pratyangira Devi isn't mentioned at all. Maybe she's mentioned in later versions of the Ramayana.

Comment: I just heard the story from people in my family.  I think multiple Tamil and Telegu movies have been made about it.  By the way, the Chenchu tribe to this day considers Narasimha to be their brother-in-law, because they regard Chenchu Lakshmi as their sister.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Goddess Lakshmi was born as Chenchu Lakshmi to a tribal head and People of this tribe live in seclusion in [Nallamala Hills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nallamala_Hills). After Narasimha killing Hiranyakasipa at [Ahobilam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahobilam),He left to forest and married her. BTW, Sri Sailam, 2nd Jyotirlinga, is situated in Nallamala Hills.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, I know the story of Chenchu Lakshmi.  I just don't know whether it has a scriptural basis or whether it's just folklore.