# Lord Sarabeswara

Tags: shiva, narasimha

Lord Narasimha after killing Hiranya drank blood. He could not control. As usual all went to Siva and requested him to control Narasimha. Siva and Narasimha had gruelling fight and at last Narasimha fell on the ground with folded hands in front of siva. Any puranic reference for this. Shiva puranam  says about Shiva's bravery.Vishu puranam speaks about Vishnu's bravery. As Narsimha cannot be overthrown by anybody bcoz  he is the supreme God.  Narasimha  [Vishnu] is the creator,  preserver and destroyer. After Vishnu it is Brahma  and then only Shiva.

Comment: That answer has story taken from Shiva Purana. So, exactly a duplicate.

Comment: Because you are a saiva sect you will  tell as duplicate----

Comment: It is a story only  not a happening. You agreed it  is a story.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan First of all, Story can be real or imaginary (see meaning of word "Story"). Second, You asked Puranic reference, and that question has answer taken from Shiva Purana. And finally, don't assume i belong to Shiva sect just by seeing my Profile picture and info on profile page.

Comment: There is no answer for that--Shiva purana which chapter Lord sarabeswara avatarred? etc etc  and the consequences etc etc--

Comment: You answer only shiva related questions not even a Vishnu realted question. Hence I came to a conclusion that u r a strong saivism.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan See Keshav's answer and excerpt he linked. I also answered Vishnu related questions. But, i answer only topics i read or i know,

Comment: Bcoz Keshav refers and answers and provides requisite answers -I had a chat with him and he said only 3 vasihnavites are there  he  me and Krishna. I do not blame on anybody. Whatever you know u r answering  99% saiva related questions. Do not criticise other's questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44675/discussion-between-parthasarathy-raghavan-and-the-destroyer).

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - The question has been answered from a shaivate point of view and Vaishnavate point of view quoting puranas and other Scriptures. Shaivate view from Shiva purana is given as one answer and I have provided another answer quoting various other puranas from Vaishnavate point of view.  Please check the answers to the question " What is the story of Sharabha". Hope it helps. We can discuss offline , if required

Comment: Might be offtopic,but i'm sad to say this.This hatred btween Vishnu devotees and Shiva is only to be found mostly in Southern India apart from ofcourse Isckon who propagte such haterd.This hatred is non existent in Northern India which is ideally the way it shud be.

Comment: In modern Hinduism, "Brahmavidya" is used to mean a spiritual study of Hindu scriptures with the aim of realizing the ultimate reality. Different modern Hindu leaders have defined it in the context of their own systems of philosophy.The "Ultimate Reality" is one, the paths have to converge on that reality.

Comment: @Rickross - Either you are myopic or one of those those who is a neo phyte who blindly believes in tantric aspects being propagated by many of Neo - modern gurus of North India. In fact, the hatred of Shiva devotees towards Vishnu and Vaishnavas is equally bad and worse in North or South India and it is very evident from any body who calls himself a Advaitin, but acts like a shaivate or Shakta always. naturally, you being pro- shaivate will try to support them and will oblivious to facts. But, that is the problem with your perception. So, please get your facts right before airing your views.

Comment: @Krishna i forgot to add "so called" before devotees that's all.Rest is just fine and true.In North India no such hatred exists which is ideally the way it should be, i repeat.Even in my state i have not seen any such hatred.

Comment: @Rickross - That is why I called you myopic, as you don't want see it that as you are pro shaivate, whether you like it or not...

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan "bcoz he is the supreme God. Narasimha [Vishnu] is the creator, preserver and destroyer. After Vishnu it is Brahma and then only Shiva."--Lord Narsimha is everything and yet if u do a homa for him u need to worship Ganapaty first.What a pity isn't it?Don't u think that in this race if someone who has come first  it has to be Ganapaty ?haha

Comment: @Krishna..I'm not paying heed to ur words.I,m more close to the place of action than u are.And what facts?Are these facts published as surveys or in research articles ?Or the media carries news on them?.And don't call me by names like shaivite and vaisnavite etc.These sects are the discoveries of virtueless kaliyuga.They didn't exist in the previous 3 yugas when virtue really existed.It only appeared in late kali and more so after the advent of few so called acharyas.Real devotees don't differentiate between Gods

Comment: @Rickross--We have Thumbikai Alwar where we do puja -- hahaha--Do not think you know everything. Atleast conduct a homam and see how it fructifies you---if you have confidence on the subject learnt and on yourself---It will be meaningless argument to your comments--this is a final full stop.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44716/discussion-on-question-by-parthasarathy-raghavan-lord-sarabeswara).

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - Please read my answer to the question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/what-is-the-story-of-sharaba , from Vaishnavate point of view and if you thin you like it pls do up vote, accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @Krishna--If you read all the puranas it will be like interlinking. At times I have a doubt that these will be mere stories and is not existent. My all prarthanas are not fulfilled by Vishnu although I prayed. But a parathana to Baba yielded the positive result--not one--around 35 incidents. So when he calls you only, u can be a devotee of him. Till then you  will cite from puranas which will be mere stories. Why cannot the God punish the bandicoots and thieves who are looting the country? No answer. So there is no sanatana dharma at present. Ahankara and adharma prevails everywhere.