# Which Incarnation of Vishnu faced a lot of difficulties?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, life

Which Incarnation (probably among Dashavatar) of Vishnu had thoughest life, had to face a strong opponent, had to face a lot of Challenges.

Comment: Ram would be the usual answer, born first prince of the greatest Empire of that time, still had to go through a lot (quick summary): went with vishwamitra to kill some demons in forest, came home back married (to a princess of a minor kingdom), had to leave for 14 years of exile, lived in jungle, had his wife kidnapped, went through all of south India in search of her, fought a war with Rawan, come back home just to exile his wife (not knowing she was pregnant), almost killed his sons in a battle thereafter, damn hard life.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal I guessed the same; but I didnt know about the life story of other incarnations, so I asked this question.

Comment: @v.aggarwal All are fine but what do you mean by _"amost killed his sons"_. Raama never faught with his sons because Sage Valmiki did interfere and stopped the fight even before it could begin.

Comment: Other incarnation who faced lots of difficulties (may be even more than Raama) is Lord Parshuraama. He forced to do lots of stuff which none can even imagine. He had to go against principles of his father. Forced to chopped head of his own mother. His father was murdered. And coz of many other incident too, He most of the time used to stay in angry form. His whole life was full of suffering.

Comment: @Vishvam Heard somewhere about it actually, not aware of the actual story, So even if he didn't fought them, He might have killed them if Valmiki had not interfered.

Comment: @Vishvam please look this question >>  [Lord_Rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37502/names-of-mantra-sutra-shloka-and-stotra-from-ramayana)

Comment: this is opinion based..similarly one can say that Krishna had to face a lot of Challenges soon after his birth, Kamsa send many demonic creatures to kill him, had to face wrath of gods like Indra, Brahma (during childhood) and Shiva (during war with Banasura)..

Comment: Instead of asking who faced more challenges ask what are all challenges faced by all avatars. So that it wouldn't be an opinion based question. Based on answer you can decide who faced more challenges

Comment: I think matsya,kurma,varaha,vamana did not face any, i read somewhere about kurma samhara murti of shiva or another story where shiva broke one tusk of varaha,when vishnu became bad after completing his duty,these stories may be from saiva siddhanta,I too don't have any idea.According to linga purana virabhadra gifted shiva [Narasimha's skin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2479/20886) Parashurama,Rama,Krishna's stories are well known, I think Narasimha faced the toughest time dying in hands of sharabha.His skin becoming Shiva's hide and Skullbecominoneof the manyskulls of Shiva's garland