# Were Vishnu avatarams liberated by Shakti/Siva?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, shaivism, shakti, shakta

A page on Quora by the name "Dakshina Kali (দক্ষিণা কালী)" commented Matsya was liberated by Matsyasamharamurti, Varaha by Varahasamharamurti, Narasimha by Sharabha, Vamana by Kankalamurti; Rama and Krsna by Mahakala; and Hayagriva and Mohini by Adiparashakti. Could somebody elaborate this with sources?

Comment: Liberation of Narasimha by Sarabha is mentioned in Satarudra Samhita from Shiva Purana. But, never happened to others avatars like this.

Answer (score 3):

I have only came across by the Sarabha Incident.
So the authority(Pramana) is like this in our dharma.
Shruti(Vedas)>Itihas(Ramayan Mahabharat)>Smriti(Purans)
So all other incidents except the Nrusimha Sarabha is mentioned in Smritis only not in Shrutis also Narayan cannot be killed or any of his avatarams he does not leave his body without his wish.
[ KMG (MB) — 12.343 ]
I was never born. I never take birth. Nor shall I ever be born. I am the Kshetrajna of all creatures. Hence am I called by the name of Aja (unborn).
[ Bori CE (MB) — 1658(330) ]
O descendant of the Bharata lineage! In the world, the illustrious Dharma is known by the name of Vrisha. Thus, in the words of Nighantuka, I am known as the supreme Vrisha. Kapi is said to be the best among boars and Vrisha is said to be the best among dharma. Therefore, Prajapati Kashyapa has addressed me as Vrishakapi. I am without beginning, without middle and without end. The gods and the asuras have never been able to comprehend my beginning, my middle, or my end. I have been praised as the lord, the lord who is a witness to the worlds. O Dhananjaya! I do not hear, or cause to be heard, anything that is inauspicious. I do not accept anything that is wicked. Hence, I am Shuchishrava.
Also many such verses are in bhagvad gita(which is itihasa) which you can refer so by the shruti rule all the ones mentioned in smritis can be refuted.
Now back to Sarabha incident.
The incident starts with Sarabha finding Vishnu
“vishNu” – all-pervasive. The idea is that Sharabha was searching for and moving towards the One who is already everywhere and hence can never be caught unawares – such is the wonder of the incident. BhagavAn can appear out of the pillar in an instant and as the isavasya Upanishad says, he overtakes the moving as he pervades everywhere. So, the question of Sharabha arriving unlooked for does not arise.
Nrusimha Tapaniya Upanihad which is well quoted by well known acharyas like Ramanuja Adi Shankara etc. calls Narasimha, who is sarvasaktan, and tavasastavIyan (stronger than the strongest). Here, the quality of agatitagaTanA sAmarthyam (reconciling contradictions) is also seen in BhagavAn Narasimha.So Sarabha incident holds no authority in front of shruti.
So What about Sarabha upanishad? you may ask answer is this upanishad was never quoted by a single Shaiv acharya before 15th century never did Adi Shankara quoted from this upanishad neither did other scholars so according to me it is a recent upanishad added whatever may be the case the answer to your question is No avatar of Vishnu were liberated by Śiva or Adishakti it holds no authority.

Answer (score 0):

The Basis of This Appears to be from Skanda Purana.

> 17. If you had not killed Nṛhari (Man-lion) by assuming the form of a Śarabha (i.e. a fabulous eight-footed animal) alone, he would have
>     destroyed the universe like Hiraṇyakaśipu.
>
> **18. In the ocean at the end of the Kalpa you were the boatman who dragged Hari in the forms of Fish, Tortoise, Boar and Man-lion after
> binding him with the king of serpents for cords.**

~ **[Skanda Purana, Arunachala Khanda (uttarardha) Chapter 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370669.html)**

As many know, there are two versions of the Skanda purana, one divided to Khandas and one Samhitas. The Samhita Version Of the Skanda Purana also makes an alleged reference to this.

> पीत्वा तचाप्यरक्षस्त्वं तादृशः कंगतोऽधुना । गजान्धकासुरौ हत्वा
> पालयामास वै सुशन (भवान्) मत्स्य कूर्म वराहांश्च नारसिंह त्रिविक्रम
> हत्वा नेत्रेव मीनस्य कमठस्यास्थि कर्कशम् ॥ ४१ वराहस्यच दंष्ट्रांच
> नृसिंहस्य स्वयं तथा । त्रिविक्रमस्य पृष्ठास्थि गृहीत्वैव पुरा वयम् ॥
> ४२

... The Gist of Which translates to-

> Matsya's eyes, Kurma's bones, Varaha's teeth, Narasimha's skin,
> and Vamana's vertebral column , were all seized by Lord Shiva after
> they were liberated by him.

**~ Skanda Purāṇam Shankar Samhita, Virmahendra Khanda, 2.41-42**

Aside from that, Sukshma Agama, A saivagama While Listing the Leela Murtis of Shiva, Lists A Murti of His which stated to have Liberated Nrsimha, Varaha, Kurma, Matsya etc.

[image]

The Same Saivagama also narrates the Story of The Liberation of Lord Vamana at the hands of Kankala-murti Shiva.

[image]

Source-

**[Sukshma Agama, Uttara Bhaaga, Kriya Paada, Patala 2](https://archive.org/details/SukshmagamaVrajVallabhDwivedi/page/n39/mode/2up?view=theater)**

Answer (score -4):

Yes,

> Let there be adoration to that Rudra, who, the ancient Lord, killed the terrible and troublesome incarnations of Vishnu, namely, Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narasimha, and Vamana; who troubled Suresha (Indra) by making him tired and who reduced Manmata (Kama) and Yama into ashes. (Sharabha Upanishad 13).

> “In this, both Balarama and Kesava (Krishna) after causing the extermination of their race, their hour having come, themselves did not rise superior to the sway of all-destroying Kala”. (MBH 1:2:350).

> Mahadev killed all the incarnations of Lord Vishnu. (Shankar Samhita, Virmahendra Khanda, 2.41-42).

Sharabha Murti from Sharabha Upanishad of Athaeva Veda and Taittiriya Aranyaka of Yajur Veda.

**Sharabha Upanishad.:**

> *स एकः श्रेष्ठश्च सर्वशास्ता स एव वरिष्ठश्च ।
> यो घोरं वेषमास्थाय शरभाख्यं महेश्वरः ।
> नृसिंहं लोकहन्तारं संजघान महाबलः ॥ ४॥*
>
> ***हरिं हरन्तं** पादाभ्यामनुयान्ति सुरेश्वराः ।
> मावधीः पुरुषं विष्णुं विक्रमस्व महानसि ॥ ५॥*
>
> *कृपया भगवान्विष्णुं विददार नखैः खरैः ।
> चर्माम्बरो महावीरो वीरभद्रो बभूव ह ॥ ६॥*
>
> *"That Maheshvara, full of supreme power had beheaded (killed) Narasimha who was destroying the world by holding a gigantic form of Sharabha"- 4*
>
> *" When Lord Rudra, the God of all had abducted Lord Vishnu by catching his foot, all gods prayed him that he should have mercy on Lord Vishnu and should not slaughter him. Lord Rudra had badly pierced the body of Lord Vishnu by stern blows of his acute nails. The most chivalrous Lord Rudra has been addressed as Virabhadra at that time when he put on leather apparel of Narsimha at that moment"- 5-6*

**YajurVeda's Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.49.1 says.:-**

> ***hariM harantam** anuyanti devAH | vishvasyeshAnaM vRiShabhaM matInAM ||*
>
> *"Salutations to Lord Hara who ends up his own form Hari, who's adored by all devas, who's the lord of universe."*

Commenting on it Sri Sayanacharya have also accepted this fact as mentioned [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51879/20968).

Even, Sri Adi Shankaracharya ji also have acknowledged Lord Sharabha liberating Lord Vishnu's avatars in his Prapancha Sara Tantra 25.63 as mentioned [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56953/20968) of mine.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: यूयं जनाः बर्नोल् इत्यस्य उपयोगं कुर्वन्तु।