# After a Vishnu avatara is ended, does that avatara usually permanently merge back into Vishnu?

Tags: krishna, rama, avatars

If you take Rama and Krishna, they both die in their human form and go back to Vaikuntha and merge into Vishnu.

On the other hand, the Varaha Avatara is said to be permanent and lives at the Venkateshwara hill in Tirupati.

Are there scriptures that say Rama or Krishna are permanently present on the earth?

Even Krishna says in the Gita that he takes avatars only periodically when adharma predominates.

Answer (score -1):

Except the Chiranjeevi Avatars everyone got liberated.

Chiranjivi Shloka.:

> “Aswathama Balir Vyaso Hanumanash cha Vibhishana Krupacharya cha Parashuramam Saptatah Chirjeevanam”.
>
> Which means that Aswathama, King Mahabali, Veda Vyasa, Hanuman , Vibhishana , Krupacharya and Lord Parashuram are death-defying or imperishable personalities.

Even, Varaha Avatara is also not permanent.

Sri Skanda Purana 2.1.1 mentions the residence of Lord Varaha and Mata Bhu Devi after Hiranyaksha incident.

> 96. On the western bank of Svāmipuṣkariṇī, honoured by all the worlds, remains seated the Lord having the face of Boar (along with his wife Earth). He is worshipped there by the leading sages, Vaikhānasas (‘anchorites’) of great magnificence, noble souls on a par with Brahmā.

Sri Kalika Upa Purana, Chapter Sarasar Nirupam, describes what happened after that :

> Lord Varaha himself had gone to a mountain named Lokalok and there he started living with his wife Varahi, who was the most beautiful lady Earth (Prithvi).

They had 3 sons named Suvrtta, Kanaka and Ghora and due to their Mayhem Lord Sharabha had to kill all the 3 sons, Yagna Varaha and Narasimha who came to help them  [as mentioned in this answer.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54995/20968).

Even Sri Adi Shankaracharya in his Prapancha Sara tantra glorifies Sharabheshvara as supreme form of Shiva who liberated the tusked Boar form of Lord Vishnu i.e Varaha which is in accordance with Kalika purana.

Prapancha Sara Tantra 25.63.:

> Obeisance To the Enemy of Death and Andhaka (4 ), Who is the Destroyer of the cities ( 5 ); Obeisance to Thee Who didst rend the tusked Boar (6 ), Obeisance ever to Thee Entwined with great poisonous serpents, Who art borne upon a great bull (7).

- Arthur Avalon in the footnote 6 to his translation of the above verse says.: The Varaha Avatara of Vishnu slain by Shiva in the form of the animal called Sharabha. Kalika Purana, Ch. 29.
- Arthur Avalon's footnote: 7.: The Vahana of Shiva. The bull of Shiva is Vishnu who assumed that form to support Shiva at the time the latter killed Tripuras. Shiva had for the purpose of the combat to assume so great a size using as his arrow the Sumeru Mountain that the Earth could not support Him, on which Vishnu assumed the form of a Bull to uphold Him. Vrishaaha. ( Bull ) means Dharma. Shiva {Beneficence ) rests on Dharma.

Sri Linga Purana 1.94.:

> 26b-27. When Varāha the lord had gone back to milk ocean after leaving off the form of the boar, the earth shook again. The curved fangs of intelligent lord of Devas, pressed down by the weight of the earth fell down there.
>
> 28-30. Bhava, the lord of the universe, who casually went that way, saw that curved fang and took it up for his own embellishment.

> Let there be adoration to that Rudra, who, the ancient Lord, killed the terrible and troublesome incarnations of Vishnu, namely, Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narasimha, and Vamana; who troubled Suresha (Indra) by making him tired and who reduced Manmata (Kama) and Yama into ashes. (Sharabha Upanishad 13).

> “In this, both Balarama and Kesava (Krishna) after causing the extermination of their race, their hour having come, themselves did not rise superior to the sway of all-destroying Kala”. (MBH 1:2:350).

After messenger Death Yama was sent to inform Lord Rama that his avatar period was over, Lord Rama took Jala Samadhi and went to Vaikuntha.

Valmiki Ramayana. Book 7. Uttara Khand. Chapter 110.:

> Rama stepped into the waters, where-upon the Grandsire, from on high, uttered these words:—
>
> .
>
> Hearing these words of the Grandsire, the supremely virtuous Rama formed his resolution and entered Vishnu’s abode in his body with his younger brothers.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..