# In which Yuga Narkasura was born?

Tags: gods

in which yuga Narkasura was born in Dwapara Yuga or Treta Yuga?
Who Killed Narkasura?Was Narkasura son of Bhumi and Varaha?

Comment: Where did you hear that Narakasura and Banasura were brothers?  Narakasura was the son of Bhumidevi goddess of the Earth, while Banarasura was the son of Mahabali.

Comment: Oh ok.. But which Yuga were they born?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  Sugriva mentions Narakasura in the Kishkindha Kanda of the Ramayana: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga42/kishkindha_42_frame.htm And the Ramayana took place in the 24th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, as I discuss in this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/36 So Narakasura was alive for at least 4 Mahayugas, although he may have been born all the way in the beginning of the Kalpa, considering that that's when Vishnu's incarnation Varaha married Bhumidevi.

Comment: As far as Banasura goes, Vishnu's incarnation as Vamana occurred in the 7th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara; see the Matsya Purana link in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36 But I'm not sure whether Banasura was born to Mahabali before or after his encounter with Vamana.

Comment: How can Ramayana take place in the 24th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara? It should have been taken place in the current Mahayuga i.e. 28th Mahayuga? And that too in Tetra Yuga of the current Mahayuga? And every Mahayuga must have its own Mythological story and even if Ramayana repeated in every Mahayuga, there should be some twist or difference between the Ramayanas in each Mahayuga? Isn't it?

Comment: No, people often assume that it happened in the current Mahayuga, but it didn't.  The fact that it happened in the 24th Treta Yuga is confirmed in numerous scriptures; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/36  The Ramayana isn't repeated in every Mahayuga.  In fact, I only know of one earlier time in which the Ramayana took place, and that was in a previous Mahakalpa.  It's described in the Padma Purana.  But you're right that each Mahayuga has its own incarnations and stories.

Answer (score 1):

It is said in [Purans](http://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter59.html) that Narakāsura was the son of Dharti,and Lord Himself in(Varaha Avtar third avtar of vishnu) **Born In Dwapara Yuga**. But he became a demon due to the bad association of BāṇaSura son of Bali. An atheist is called a demon, and it is a fact that even a person born of good parents can turn into a demon by bad association. Birth is not always the criterion of goodness; unless and until one is trained in the culture of good association, one cannot become good.

from **Srimad Bhagvatam 3.3.6**

> sutaṁ mṛdhe khaṁ vapuṣā grasantaṁ
>
> dṛṣṭvā sunābhonmathitaṁ dharitryā
>
> āmantritas tat-tanayāya śeṣaṁ
>
> dattvā tad-antaḥ-puram āviveśa

**Translation:**

> Narakāsura, the son of Dhartī, the earth, tried to grasp the whole sky, and for this he was killed by the Lord in a fight. His mother then prayed to the Lord. This led to the return of the kingdom to the son of Narakāsura, and thus the Lord entered the house of the demon.

[Here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/2-3) is how Shri Krishna Killed Narkasura  **SB 10.59.2-3:**

Answer (score 0):

Narakasura or Bhaumasura belongs to Dvapara Yuga according to the 10th Canto of Srimad Bhagavatam. Please check this website for more information:

http://krsnabook.com/ch59.html

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  That link doesn't address when Narakasura was born.  He certainly fought Krishna in the Dwapara Yuga, but he could have been born in an earlier Yuga.