# Development of Man's form along with God's Avatar

Tags: avatars

Are time varying successive forms that came about with evolution of God in Hindu view .. the same for the perceiving Man as well with God as a superior contemporary  Entity? I mean if God is in Fish form then Man the perceiver cannot be in a human form, right?

Comment: This is partially explained in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21714/12304 but modern day evolution theory is not completely aligned with scriptures...for instance  if u believe Fish incarnation in the beginning of 7th Manvantara, then 6 Manvantaras were already passed..Also Fish incarnation saved Manu so human form was there at that time...

Comment: Irrespective of the timeline - there is one theory doing rounds with some modern scholars - which state that Dashavatara is actually a description of the theory of evolution - Matsya (Fish - Aquatic), Kurma (Tortoise - Amphibious), Varaha (Boar - Mammal). Narasimha (Lion Man - evolution from primates / mammals), Vaamana (Dwarf / Pigmy)and then Parashurama (Fully Human). An interesting take!

Comment: Yes this aspect was in my mind when giving out the question; but conflicts of science and religion is best avoided here.

Comment: That is, an attempt to  graph metamorphosis of God and Man on a common time-line is fraught with difficulties of untold magnitude.