# Avatars of past manvantara

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Is there any mention on Vishnu Avatars that took birth on earth in the past Manvantara?

Comment: you want Vishnu avatars or shiva reference or both?

Comment: Closely Related or Possible duplicate of [What is chronological timeline (in Manvantara and Mahayuga) of Lord Vishnu incarnations?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar)

Answer (score 2):

**Is there any mention on Vishnu Avatars that took birth in the past Manvantaras?**

Yes, as per [Vishnu Purana - Part 3 - Chapter 1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp075.htm), below are Lord Vishnu's avtars in past Manvantara:

- Yajna was born in the Swáyambhuva or First Manwantara
- Ajita was born in the Swárochisha or Second  Manwantara
- Satya was born in the Auttami or Third Manwantara
- Hari was born in the Támasa or Fourth Manwantara
- Mánasa was born in the Raivata or Fifth Manwantara
- Vaikuntha was born in the Chákshusha or Sixth Manwantara