# RAM BIRTH IN 24TH CHATYRYUG

Tags: ramayana, matsya-purana

According to matsya puran ram took avatara in tretayug of 24th cahturyuga. Currently the yug is 28th. Ram did not took avtara in this chaturyuga??

Comment: Acording to puranas Vishnu took Avataras and Rama was one among them.   Please rephrase your question

Comment: There are four yug in one chaturyug.. 28th chaturyug is passing now (in 1 day of brahma). In every chaturyug there is one treta yug. But matsya puran mentions that Ram took avatar in 24th chaturyug so in 28th charyug ram did not take birth?

Comment: short answer to your question - yes, Sri Rama took birth in 24th Chaturyuga and not in 28th chaturyuga

Comment: @Carmensandiego so which avatar incarnated in Treta Yug of 28th ChaturYuga?

Comment: @RishX -  I don't think there was any significant avatar in treta yuga of 28th chaturyuga

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is chronological timeline (in Manvantara and Mahayuga) of Lord Vishnu incarnations?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar)