# Does Lord Parashurama have link to Ikshvaku dynasty?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, parashurama

As per [Mahabharata Vana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03116.htm) , Parashurama's maternal grandfater was King Prasenajit.

As per [Valmiki Ramayana Ayodhya Kanda Sarga 110 verse 13](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga110/ayodhya_110_frame.htm), one of Lord Rama's ancestor was Prasenajit

Are they the same person ? Looking for a scripture reference

Comment: Very interesting. it seems plausible since Prasenjit would have been born in the 19th Mahayuga much before Shri Rama's time in 24th Mahayuga.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal - I think so too . There seems no good to reason to mention Prasenjit from Ikshvaku lineage in Ramayana as being the second child he was not even heir to the throne

Comment: Furthermore , grandfather of Prasenjit (from Ikshvaku dynasty) is King Mandhata. Mandhata is said to have been born in 15th Treta Yuga - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21996/18974 . So for sure Prasenjit was born in or after 15th Treta Yuga.

Comment: Rama was Kshatriya and Parshuram was Brahmin from birth.

Comment: @Sanatan Darshan - No one is denying that.

Comment: Parshuram's father was Brahmin yes but his mother Renuka was a Kshatriya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, King Prasanajit who was Lord Rama's ancestor was also Lord Parashurama's maternal grandfather. So Lord Parashurama has links to Ikshavaku lineage.

From [Chapter VII - Lineage of Puruvasas and Jahnu](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116003.html) of Vishnu Purana,

> Jamadagni married Reṇukā, the daughter of Reṇū, of the family of **Ikṣvāku**, and had by her the destroyer of the Kṣatriya race, Paraśurāma, who was a portion of Nārāyaṇa, the spiritual guide of the universe[14].

> “JAMADAGNI (the son of Ricīka[1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116003.html)) was a pious sage, who by the fervour of his devotions, whilst engaged in holy study, obtained entire possession of the Vedas. Having gone to king Prasenajit, he demanded in marriage his daughter Reṇukā, and the king gave her unto him.

Comment: Good to see you answering your own question which was left unanswered for long time.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - Thanks. I came across this while searching for more information on Tarakamaya war, and luckily I remembered my unanswered question.