# How to explain timing of ramayana

Tags: ramayana

How can ramayana be 7000 years old if Iceage ended 10000 ago,how do they become developed  so  fast, and  if it occurred in  some  other  yuga, then how  do we still  have  Ram setu.

Comment: 7000 is a figure derived by Western/ Modern indologists by ‘supposedly’ reconstructing some planetary positions mentioned in Srimad Valmiki Ramayana. See [timeline of Vishnu avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21996/20129)

Comment: 7000 is wrong. It happened 18 million yrs ago as mentioned in answer hyperlinked in Archit's post

Comment: Rama Setu (Adam's bridge) is a natural formation called [Tombolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombolo). There are [hundreds of tombolos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombolo#List_of_tombolos) all over the world. Also, the million-year yuga concept is only found in Puranas and Itihasas, there is no such thing in the Vedas. We should interpret Ramayana and Mahabharata (both of which contain lot of embellishments) based on History, not the other way round.

Comment: Check [this chronology](https://archive.org/details/KlausK.KlostermaierAConciseEncyclopediaOfHinduismConciseEncyclopediaOfWorldFaiths/page/n225/mode/2up) of Hindu scriptures. And [another one](https://archive.org/stream/ConstanceA.JonesJamesD.RyanEncyclopediaOfHinduism#page/n27/mode/2up).

Comment: Also, read [this](http://www.archive.cpiml.org/liberation/year_2007/october/ram_setu.htm) article from 2007.

Comment: [...In its affidavit filed in response to this, the ASI quite correctly remarked that these texts, while of undeniable mythological and devotional value, however "cannot be said to be historical record to incontrovertibly prove the existence of the characters or the occurrence of the events, depicted therein.” The affidavit also cited studies that proved that the so-called 'Ram Setu' "was not a man-made structure, but actually comprised 103 small patch reefs lying in a linear pattern with reef crest, sand cays and intermittent deep channels...]

Comment: @sv. the Sri Lanka we know it today is not Ravana’s Lanka. It’s actually Maldives.

Comment: @Archit If Maldives is Lanka, where is the Rama Setu between India and Maldives? It's gone?

Comment: @sv. :). See ramayan occurred some 4 mahayugas before. Since then we have very little left. Even things from Mahabharata (only 5000 years back) and more so so many very historically dateable temples are not traceable. Ramayana Ram setu would’ve definitely gone under water. It’s definitely not Sri Lanka (idea proposed by British) because Sri Lanka has always been referred to as Simhala, Tampraparni, Eezham (in tamil). All the so called sites have been created much later. Now why Maldives? Ramayana clearly states the setu was 100 yojana (1200-1300 km) so is the distance between rameshwaram and m

Comment: Moreover, it is supposed to be well known that Lanka was situated at the equator in the same longitude as Ujjayini and Kurukshetra (or Rohtak) Maldives falls roughly there in the same line with minor variation. Not only that, there’s supposed to be a story in Vayu Purana where Vayudeva blew a portion of Meru parvat and it landed in the ocean. This was called malayadvipa. It says Lanka was situated on Malayadvipa where trikutachala etc were there. Note:- before Islam etc Mālādivu (tamil for malayadvipa) became Maldives. Their language is called divehi related to dvipa or island language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110953/discussion-between-archit-and-sv).

Comment: @sv. Now my problem with Maldives : if it was Maldives then Ramayana describes elephants and all roaming in Lanka and a full army being able to fit. Looking at what it is PRESENTLY it can’t accomodate medium land animals let alone four tusked elephants. Further it is so low and it seems little suspicious how Ravana could establish a whole kingdom on the island. Vibhishana is supposed to be alive, we don’t find any remains of his palace or residence or cave. But I can say with 100% surety Sri Lanka is not Lanka.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if ASI or GSI did some analysis they won't find any trace of Rama Setu even near Maldives. If Hanuman was so powerful as Ramayana claims, he can easily carry entire vanara-sena on his shoulders. There is no need of a Rama Setu. Assuming the whole thing is historical, some say the setting for the original Ramayana story was within mainland India which makes a lot of sense. So original Lanka was some place near Madhya Pradesh. It's entirely possible poets after Valmiki expanded his work to 20K+ verses considering much of Balakanda and Uttarakanda are interpolations. @Archit

Comment: @sv. What if it sunk? We have a question on the site asking what happened to Ram setu afterwards, though the answer is a little vague. If it happened in mainland Godavari and Panchavati wouldn’t find mention. Also if it happened in Madhya Pradesh, that’s pretty close to Ayodhya and Bharat would’ve come to know, he would’ve sent the army immediately. Ramji wouldn’t need Sugriva’s help. The reason they left Chitrakuta (UP and MP) was also so Ayodhya people don’t come. They went to Dandakaranya- further southern chhattisgarh (Gond tribal region) then Godavari etc. How to explain Rameshwaram?

Comment: //How to explain Rameshwaram?// - Going back to what I said earlier: "We should interpret Ramayana and Mahabharata (both of which contain lot of embellishments) based on History, not the other way round." It's best not to mix history and mythology. If you do you'll find lot of contradictions. Ultimately, it comes down to which pramana (pratyaksha, anumana or shabda) you give more importance. ASI/GSI reports based on carbon dating are like pratyaksha. 'Vibhishana is supposed to be alive' - this contradicts both Vedas and Science which say humans usually live only for around 100 years. @Archit

Comment: Point, Agree. But I can’t agree on the fact that it happened in central India. They would’ve definitely crossed the sea, it can’t be in central India.