# Is there any text that talks about events that happened in previous manvantara?

Tags: history, manvantara

In Hinduism there is a concept of cyclic time. Manvantara is a unit of time.

So is there any text that talks about events that happened in previous manvantara.

Comment: Please see this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When Narada met Vyasa and asked him to write Bhagavata, he narrates a story from previous manvantara.

> **O Muni, in the last millennium I was born** as the son of a certain maidservant engaged in the service of brāhmaṇas who were following the
> principles of Vedānta. When they were living together during the four
> months of the rainy season, I was engaged in their personal
> service.(SB 1.5.23)
>
> O Vyāsadeva, in that association and by the mercy of those great
> Vedāntists, I could hear them describe the attractive activities of
> Lord Kṛṣṇa. And thus listening attentively, my taste for hearing of
> the Personality of Godhead increased at every step.(SB 1.5.26)
>
> As they were leaving, those bhakti-vedāntas, who are very kind to
> poor-hearted souls, instructed me in that most confidential subject
> which is instructed by the Personality of Godhead Himself.(SB 1.5.30)
>
> After that, under the shadow of a banyan tree in an uninhabited forest
> I began to meditate upon the Supersoul situated within, using my
> intelligence, as I had learned from liberated souls. As soon as I
> began to meditate upon the lotus feet of the Personality of Godhead
> with my mind transformed in transcendental love, tears rolled down my
> eyes, and without delay the Personality of Godhead, Śrī Kṛṣṇa,
> appeared on the lotus of my heart.(SB 1.6.15-16)

Comment: Hmmm...is this iskcon translation? Supersoul, personality of godhead etc. No advaita translator will use such words. These are certainly western words.

Comment: Yes it is sir. I only have that in online. @GIRIBLR

Comment: @GIRIBLR is there anything wrong with iskon translation.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru "O Muni, in the last millennium I was born" there is a difference between manvantara and millennium.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru You can use https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n217/mode/2up or buy Bhagavata Purana With English Translation by Gita Press that includes a good translation. I have nothing against iskcon but I do not like words like supersoul etc. Maybe i am biased because of advaita. Here, what does millenium mean..1000 years as conventionally meant? The original text means manvantra ? as the MLD version says former cycle of ages.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah you are right. I will edit my answer to find another story if possible.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Sir I do have Motilal edition but its difficult to copy paste. Anyways there's a Bhagavata in short by Swami Tejomayananda full in Advaitic style. PDF is there in Library Genisis. I am also biased towards Advaitha like you :) I dont know sir.

Comment: If MLD version says Former cycles of ages then it should answer your question @DarkKnight

Comment: @DarkKnight MLBD says Former Cycle of Ages. So here you go : https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n49/mode/2up