# Who is Jatukarnya the officiating priest for Vyasa?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, rishi, vyasa, matsya-purana

This excerpt from the [Matsya Puran](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nckrAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2224th%20treta%22&pg=PA138&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) mentions a certain rishi Jatukarnya as the priest designated for Vedvyas incarnation of Lord Vishnu. The same list has been shared in a [different question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7192/why-does-each-incarnation-of-vishnu-need-an-officiating-priest).

For a person to be the officiating priest of the compiler of Vedas, he has to be exceptionally gifted! I want to know **who this rishi is and if there are any details mentioned about his genealogy or life in any scripture.**

Comment: A Jatukarnya  i know is Agnivesya, son of Devadatta. https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/2/21

Comment: Yes I came across that somewhere but who is Devdatta? I want to understand the whole lineage and life story if possible. If he is serving as the priest to Vedvyas he has to be someone really knowledgeable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jatukarnya and Jatukarna are the same as [Vayu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vayu_purana/lomaharshana_and_the_other_sages.html) mentions:

> The great Vedavyasa was born as Satyavati‘s son. Vedavyasa learnt the Vedas from the great sage Jatukarna. He also composed the Mahabharata and the Puranas.

**Jatukarnya or Jatukarna was the 27th Vyasa**.

In [Vishnu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vishnu_purana/veda_vyasa_and_significance_of_brahmagyan.html), Parasar (father of Krishna Dvaipayana or 28th Vyasa) says:

> Jatukarna was 27th Vyasa after him (26th Vyasa).

[image]

[Kurma Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/veda_vyasa.html) also mentions Jatukarna as the 27th Vyasa.

[image]

[Linga Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/linga_purana/incarnations_of_manu_and_vyasa.html) also mentions Jatukarna as the 27th Vyasa.

**Update as asked by questioner:**

Descending in order from the seminal dynasty of Nariṣyanta, another son of **Manu**, were Citrasena, Ṛkṣa, Mīḍhvān, Pūrṇa, Indrasena, Vītihotra, Satyaśravā, Uruśravā and Devadatta. From Devadatta came a son known as Agniveśya, who was the fire-god Agni himself. This son, who was a celebrated saint, was well known as Kānīna and Jātūkarṇya. From Agniveśya came a brahminical dynasty known as Āgniveśyāyana. (**Source**: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/2)

**Note**: At first glance it seems that this is same Jātūkarṇya (who was priest of Vyasa) but still this is subject for verification. If some one can provide counter arguments, this can be searched further.

Comment: Thanks so much for that info. A former Vyas would certainly qualify to be the priest for the future Vyas! But I want to know more about his genealogy and his life story. Who was he, where did he come from, what did he do?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Who was he, where did he come from --updated in answer; what did he do -- he was 27th Vyasa and priest of 28th Vyasa :)

Comment: Haha thank you for the update if no one else posts anything to counter this else I'll select your answer. :)