# Why don't we perform pooja to the powerful Parashurama?

Tags: history

According to an answer to a question, Parashurama is powerful and attains powers by doing penance in every yuga and transfers them to the avatars of lord Vishnu . In the same way he transfers his powers to lord Rama and gives Sudarshan chakra to Lord Krishna when he was in need of it, as he is the protector of it.Then why won't we perform pooja to Parashurama though he is powerful compared to other avatars, why was he not recognized in the world, why his story was not described in any book?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Mr.Ramesh. Good query to start. I recommend you to view other's way of questioning in this site. Try to summarise your question.

Comment: 1. His story is described in the Bhagavata purana , the ramayana and dattatreya charitra/tripura rahasya too. 2. Each yuga has its designated archavatara and lord parasurama is not one such. He may be worshipped as a guru swarupa. 3. He is not necessarily more powerful than the other avataras. Each avatara has a defined purpose and Lord parasurama served(s) his chosen / designated dharma.

Comment: I suggest you change the question to Why can't we worship Parashurama instead of My Question To You.

Comment: Related question [Why isn't Parashurama worshipped like the other Vishnu Avatars?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/why-isnt-parashurama-worshipped-like-the-other-vishnu-avatars)